# Downloading Ubuntu

Tags: downloads

I just downloaded the file with the extension ".iso". I click on it and nothing happens. I opened up VirtualBox to try and use it and I get an error message about a kernel module. (Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)). What do I do now?

Answer (score 2):

You can follow the Ubuntu tutorials to verify and create bootable media:

[How to verify your Ubuntu download](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu?_ga=2.37567072.1170558116.1522984024-1570023986.1517891776#0)

[Create a bootable USB stick on Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#0)

[How to burn a DVD on Ubuntu](https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-burn-a-dvd-on-ubuntu#0)

If needed you can re-download Ubuntu iso install images from [Ubuntu Releases](http://releases.ubuntu.com/)

Answer (score 0):

Check the Integrity of it. Try to Redownload it and use `rufus` to boot it up using usb as you can try ubuntu first without installing it, if you decided to keep it you can just open install ubuntu x.x.x and it will guide you Through installation